# How to take specific char from csv file?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to neo4j and i need your help!

I have create an article node in neo4j and i want to read a csv file which contains info about citations among articles (articleId, --[Cites]->,articleId). The format of csv file follows

```
"1001   9910248"
"1001   9910268"
"9304045    9204040"
"9308122    9203084"
"9308122    9204035"
"9308122    9205041
```

1001 is an id of one article and 9910248 is an id of another article. I want to read this file and create the following relationship  (article)-[:CITES]->(article). How could i do that?

I have tried the below but it didn't work.

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///C:/Citations.csv" AS line
FIELDTERMINATOR "\t" 
MERGE (article:Article {id: line[0]})
WITH article, SPLIT(article.id, " ") AS art
MERGE (article)-[:CITES]->(toarticle:TArticle {id: art})
```

Answer (score 1):

I have copied your CSV content and put it in a `data.csv` file and tried to treat it as a `tsv` format, which didn't work since probably the separating characters are not tabs.

Loading the file as CSV in the browser output the following as rows :

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///data.csv" AS row
RETURN row

╒══════════════════════╕
│"row"                 │
╞══════════════════════╡
│["1001   9910248"]    │
├──────────────────────┤
│["1001   9910268"]    │
├──────────────────────┤
│["9304045    9204040"]│
├──────────────────────┤
│["9308122    9203084"]│
├──────────────────────┤
│["9308122    9204035"]│
├──────────────────────┤
│["9308122    9205041"]│
└──────────────────────┘
```

Which means that there is only one column.

We can then split the cell elements on a whitespace character :

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///data.csv" AS row
RETURN row[0], split(row[0], " ")

Text
Code
╒════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════╕
│"row[0]"            │"split(row[0], " ")"          │
╞════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════╡
│"1001   9910248"    │["1001","","","9910248"]      │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┤
│"1001   9910268"    │["1001","","","9910268"]      │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┤
│"9304045    9204040"│["9304045","","","","9204040"]│
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┤
│"9308122    9203084"│["9308122","","","","9203084"]│
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┤
│"9308122    9204035"│["9308122","","","","9204035"]│
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┤
│"9308122    9205041"│["9308122","","","","9205041"]│
└────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┘
```

As you can see, there is more than one whitespace between the ids in each cell, which results in arrays of elements with different sizes.

The solution is to take the first and last elements of each collection :

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///data.csv" AS row
WITH split(row[0], " ") AS elements
RETURN head(elements) AS article1, last(elements) AS article2

╒══════════╤══════════╕
│"article1"│"article2"│
╞══════════╪══════════╡
│"1001"    │"9910248" │
├──────────┼──────────┤
│"1001"    │"9910268" │
├──────────┼──────────┤
│"9304045" │"9204040" │
├──────────┼──────────┤
│"9308122" │"9203084" │
├──────────┼──────────┤
│"9308122" │"9204035" │
├──────────┼──────────┤
│"9308122" │"9205041" │
└──────────┴──────────┘
```

You can now use these ids to merge articles and the cites relationship :

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///data.csv" AS row
WITH split(row[0], " ") AS elements
WITH head(elements) AS article1, last(elements) AS article2
MERGE (a1:Article {id: article1})
MERGE (a2:Article {id: article2})
MERGE (a1)-[:CITES]->(a2)
```

[image]

In case you would like to treat ids as numbers, you need to cast it to integers :

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///data.csv" AS row
WITH split(row[0], " ") AS elements
WITH head(elements) AS article1, last(elements) AS article2
MERGE (a1:Article {id: toInteger(article1)})
MERGE (a2:Article {id: toInteger(article2)})
MERGE (a1)-[:CITES]->(a2)
```

---

*EDIT* based on the given CSV file on Github

This CSV file could be parsed as TSV, the heap issue is probably because you don't have an index on `:Article(id)`, so start with that :

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Article(id)
```

Then you can load as TSV file directly from Github (it completed in 6 seconds on my laptop) :

```
LOAD CSV FROM "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anpetsa/neo4j/main/Citations.csv" AS row
WITH split(row[0], " ") AS elements
WITH head(elements) AS article1, last(elements) AS article2
MERGE (a1:Article {id: toInteger(article1)})
MERGE (a2:Article {id: toInteger(article2)})
MERGE (a1)-[:CITES]->(a2)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I tried your code but i took java heep space error. Is it possible the error is related with csv file? i' ll try to upload csv file right now.

Comment: @person I edit the answer with an additional section based on your given file

Comment: i tried to run your code and i took the below 
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SemanticError
Cannot merge the following node because of null property value for 'id': (a1:Article {id: null}) (Failure when processing file '/anpetsa/neo4j/main/Citations.csv' on line 1.)

i have also tried id as string but i took 
MERGE (a1:Article {id: article1})
MERGE (a2:Article {id: article2})
Error:
Neo.TransientError.General.OutOfMemoryError. Maybe it is fault of my laptop?

Comment: finaly i did it, but i took the below view. How is it possible to run the same code and we received different results?